# Replace or updates null values with the sum of amount spend for customers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, sum

At first, I have a table looks like as below:

```
cust_id/Bill_amt/Brand/BrandA/BrandB/Total_value
100/350/A/NULL  /NULL/NULL
100/250/A/NULL/NULL/NULL
100/100/B/NULL  /NULL/NULL
300/200/B/NULL  /NULL/NULL
```

I would like to replace the 'null' values with the amount of spend for the same customer, as you can see from the above table, there is repeated customers with cust_id 100, this is because this customer purchase both brand A and B at different dates, thus, I need your help to sum up everything for that customer in one row, after putting everything in one row, you will notice that there is 3 rows with the same record (duplication), which is shown as below:

```
cust_id/Bill_amt/Brand/BrandA/BrandB/Total_value
100/350/A/600/100/700
100/250/A/600/100/700
100/100/B/600/100/700
300/200/B/0/200/200
```

For example,cust_id 100 spend $600(350+250) for brand A, and this customer only spend $100 (look at the 3rd row of cutsomer_id 100) for brand B, thus, the total value is $700 (600+100).

I hope this explanation is clear enough for you.

After update the table as shown below, we will remove the duplicates by ourselves.

Please kindly provide us the SQL query to help us to replace or update the 'null' values with the sum of bill_amt as we have 200000 plus record to do it.

Thank you very much for taking your time to reply us.

Comment: You need to normalize your database.

Comment: @Leifingson may you explain more on that?

Comment: instead of focusing on how to query, your duplication problem is because the table is not normalized. You have a M:N relationship which requires an intersection table between cust_id's and respective purchases. That way a query would be as simple as querying the cust-id's and their purchases.

Answer (score 0):

why do you need BrandA,BrandB,Total_value column ?that is not require.

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT cust_id, 
                brand, 
                Sum(bill_amt) bill_amt 
         FROM   @t 
         GROUP  BY rollup( cust_id, brand )) 
UPDATE @t 
SET    branda = COALESCE(a.bill_amt, 0), 
       brandb = COALESCE(c.bill_amt, 0), 
       total_value = COALESCE(d.bill_amt, 0) 
FROM   @t b 
       LEFT JOIN cte a 
              ON a.cust_id = b.cust_id 
                 AND a.brand = 'A' 
       LEFT JOIN cte c 
              ON b.cust_id = c.cust_id 
                 AND c.brand = 'B' 
       LEFT JOIN cte d 
              ON b.cust_id = d.cust_id 
                 AND d.brand IS NULL 

SELECT * 
FROM   @t
```